# angular service for querying URL query parametrs

Tags: angular, query-string

I'm trying to create a service in angular 5, which will query the URL parameters, extract required parameters and assign it to  specific type of interface which I created. I tried this, but it is not working:

```
export class UrlQueryService {

  urlParams = {} as UrlQueryParams;

  constructor( private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  getParams() {
    this.route.queryParams.
    subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.urlParams.id = params['id'];
        this.urlParams.name = params['name']

      }

    )

    return this.urlParams;
  }

}
```

I wanted my service return parameters, but when I cal this service in my component I'm getting 'id' and 'name' undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
export class UrlQueryService {

  urlParams = {} as UrlQueryParams;

  constructor( private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

//subscribe in constructor / onInit
    this.route.queryParams.
    subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.urlParams.id = params['id'];
        this.urlParams.name = params['name']

      }

    )

//
  }

  getParams() {
    return this.urlParams;
  }

}
```

One time subscribe is enough. when you keep subscribing each time you call the method you will face troubles.

Note:
This example works for this situation: URL = "http://someting.com/?param1=ex1&param2=123

In the Heroes example, the params look like this: "http://something.com/param1/param2
In this situation you get the params by this code:

```js
    this.urlParams.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.urlParams.name = this.route.snapshot.params.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular router sends the parameters to target component, and only it will be able to read those parameters. I also had a similar problem, and it seems that the router shares the params only with the target component, not with service.

However, you can use router events in service like RoutesRecognized to access the url parameters.